# How to create SPList from custom template using SharePoint 2013 REST API?

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, splist, sharepoint-listtemplate

MSDN suggests passing the following properties to create a list using SP 2013 REST API in javascript:

```
{
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 
    'AllowContentTypes': true, 
    'BaseTemplate': 100,
    'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
    'Title': name
}
```

However it always fails if I pass my custom template (**10000**) as a BaseTemplate. 
This list template does exist in web list template collection, and I can without any problem create a list based on this template from the UI.